# Location of double bond in 1,3-dimethylcyclohexene

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, nomenclature

Why is the double bond in [1,3-dimethylcyclohexene](http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.121382.html) located between the alkyl subtituents? Does it have to be this way or is this just the most common form?

Comment: You are going through wrong way.. First, the structure of molecules comes then comes the name. And to your written molecule you have to consider one of the double-bonded carbon as the 1 carbon. Then, you have to count clockwise or anticlockwise for the number lpcant carbon. But in case of different counting available you have to ensure that on first differnce between the number of locant the name has the lowest number. and your given name is just the result of this procedure.

Answer (score 4):

In unsubstituted cyclohexene, the double bond is always allocated the locant ‘1’. When alone, the locant ‘1’ is omitted in the name (see Subsection P-31.1.3.1 in the current version of *[Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry – IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069-fp001)*). Thus, the preferred IUPAC name is **cyclohexene** rather than cyclohex-1-ene.

However, if any locants are essential for defining the structure of the parent structure, then all locants shall be cited. Therefore, the name 1,3-dimethylcyclohexene is not in accordance with current IUPAC recommendations. The preferred IUPAC name for the compound that is given in the question is **1,3-dimethylcyclohex-1-ene.**

Nevertheless, the practice of omitting locants when there is no ambiguity is widespread, and the incomplete name 1,3-dimethylcyclohexene is unambiguous provided that the other relevant nomenclature rules have been applied correctly, in particular:

> **P-14.4** NUMBERING
>
> When several structural features appear in cyclic and acyclic compounds, low locants are assigned to them in the following decreasing order of seniority:
>
> (…)
>
> (e) saturation/unsaturation:
>
> (i) low locants are given to hydro/dehydro prefixes (…) and ‘ene’ and ‘yne’ endings;
>
> (ii) low locants are given first to multiple bonds as a set and then to double bonds (…);
>
> (f) detachable alphabetized prefixes, all considered together in a series of increasing numerical order;
>
> (…)

In substituted cyclohexenes, a low locant is given first to the double bond (the ‘ene’ ending) according to (e). After that, low locants are given to any substituents that are expressed as prefixes (e.g. ‘methyl’) according to (f). Therefore, it is clear that the double bond in 1,3-dimethylcyclohex-1-ene has the lowest locant ‘1’ even if it is not explicitly mentioned in the name 1,3-dimethylcyclohexene.

Comment: Thank you very much. My chemistry text book, dumbed down for physicians, does not mention anything about such intricacies of nomenclature. That there is a preferred and more precise way of naming is just not mentioned. I thought that there is some deeper reason that there could not likely be an Isomer with a double bond in another position.

Comment: @Max to be fair to your book: the recommendations are still quite recent (a mere four years), many books simply haven caught up yet. Nomenclature before that was a little bit less specific and the concept of a *preferred* IUPAC name is as recent as this. This doesn't mean that other names are incorrect, the basic rule should be that they are unambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The double bond is there because it's there and the name the name says so.

[image: dimethylcyclohexenes]

With other words, there are other [isomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomer) which all have the six-membered ring with two methyl groups in the same substitution pattern, but have the double bond at different positions.

In order to distinguish between them, these would have different names.